# Excel-QuickSum of selected range sums correct value, but subtotal at bottom of table displays "0" or "$ - "

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table of assorted values, and I have sums at the bottom of most columns.  In several columns, the value of the sum is "0" or in accounting columns "$ - ".

I know that you can't sum values that Excel reads as text, but that shouldn't be the issue as when I select any group of numbers within that range, the autosum in the bottom right corner of excel correctly calculates the count and sum.  Even when I error-check using COUNTA and COUNT functions, it shows that it is reading them as numbers.

I am pasting my formula from the "problem column" that the other columns are drawing data from.  Please let me know if there is something I can change here to solve my issue.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([@[Time in]])," ",IF(MID([@[Time in]],LEN([@[Time in]])-1,2)>=MID(K57,LEN(K57)-1,2),MID([@[Time in]],LEN([@[Time in]])-1,2)-MID(K57,LEN(K57)-1,2),MID([@[Time in]],LEN(K57)-1,2)+60-MID(K57,LEN(K57)-1,2)))
```

Basically, I am trying to calculate the difference between a start time in column I of one row, and the end time in column K of the row before it.

Thanks!

Comment: `MID` is for strings. It would be helpful for you to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1425750/edit) to provide some sample data and expected result

Comment: Thanks for replying.  The problem is that I need to enter large amounts of timestamps into an excel sheet (500-1000/week) and I found that typing the colon every time takes a stupid amount of extra time for manual data entry.  I decided to just use a 3-4 number timestamp (IE-9:37am becomes 937, 1:47pm becomes 1347).  The above formula is meant to extract the final two numbers using LEN and MID.  Then I take those numbers and find the difference to find the time elapsed between the two entries. I need to mulitply that difference by a constant (cost per minute) .

Comment: The first true condition results in a couple of spaces in the cell, instead change that to zero. Then your sum formula should work.

Comment: I found a new way to eliminate using results from MID formula as numbers in the final equation and only using them as condition verifiers. It is very clunky, and it still isn't fully error-proofed, but it does the job in most situations and the columns DO get summed!
 =IF(LEN(I67)>=LEN(K66),IF(AND(LEN(I67)=4,LEN(K66)=4,MID(K66,1,2)=MID(I67,1,2)),I67-K66,IF(AND(LEN(K66)=3,LEN(I67)=3),IF(AND(LEN(K66)=LEN(I67),MID(I67,1,1)>MID(K66,1,1)),I67-K66-40,I67-K66),I67-K66-40)),I67+1200-K66-40).

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to convert a number to a time value. See the following screenshot. The cell has then been formatted with `hh:mm`

```
=TIME(INT(C2/100),((C2/100)-INT(C2/100))*100,0)
```

This result can be used in calculations, e.g. subtracting two time values from each other to get the time difference.

[image]

Comment: If this solved your issue please mark the answer as described in the [tour]

Comment: the minutes part of the equation can be further simplified to `MOD(C2,100)`...